# How Parse website with frame with casperjs

Tags: html, parsing, frame, casperjs

I want parse a website to obtain informations.

The website had frame, and the frame doesn't load.

This is the source code of my default web page :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type"content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="webstyles.css"/>
<link rel="icon"type="image/ico"href="favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon"type="image/x-icon"href="favicon.ico"/>
<script type="text/javascript"src="commun.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var i,currCount=0;var tbl_imgs,preload_image,loaded;tbl_imgs=new Array("checkbox.png","status2.png","l_droite.png","l_trouble.png","buttons.png","paradox.png","fl.png");
preload_image=new Array();loaded=new Array();function loadImages(){for(i=0;i<tbl_imgs.length;i++){preload_image[i]=new Image();
preload_image[i].src=tbl_imgs[i];}for(i=0;i<preload_image.length;i++){loaded[i]=false;}checkLoad();
}function checkLoad(){if(currCount==preload_image.length){return;}for(i=0;i<preload_image.length;i++)
{if(loaded[i]==false&&preload_image[i].complete){loaded[i]=true;currCount++;}}timerID=setTimeout("top.checkLoad()",10);}
</script>
<title>Paradox IP Module</title></head><frameset cols="100%,0">
<frame src="waitaff.html"name="mainframe"frameborder="0"scrolling="auto"noresize="noresize"/>
<frame src="waitlive.html"name="liveframe"frameborder="0"scrolling="auto"noresize="noresize"/>
<noframes><body><p>Framesets not supported.Please upgrade your browser so that you can use this setup tool</p></body></noframes></frameset></html>
```

For exemple I want obtain this status "Disarmed" or "Armed" :
[link status](http://themaiden.free.fr/OLD/Divers/image2.png)

This is the structure of code with frame :
[Link code with frame](http://themaiden.free.fr/OLD/Divers/image3.png)

On my script casperjs I have this test :

```
// step 2 > Switch to correct Iframe + check load status
    casper.then(function() {
        this.wait(10000,function(){
            casper.waitFor(function() {
                return this.withFrame('mainframe', function() {});
            }, function() {
                    this.withFrame('mainframe', function() {
                        this.echo(this.getHTML());
                        this.capture('capture4.png');
```

The frame doesn't load and my check doesn't work.

Can you help me ? I want retreive some informations like status "Disarmed" on my webpage.

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot of the page to see if the frame loads? Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors. Btw, your `casper.waitFor()` is not waiting, it is immediately progressing. `withFrame` returns `casper`

Comment: When the website charge I have this page on my screenshot : http://themaiden.free.fr/OLD/Divers/image3.png

Comment: I mean with casper: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#capture

Comment: Yes, on my capture with casper the frame is loaded.

Comment: Then why do you say that the frame hasn't loaded? *The website had frame, and the frame doesn't load.*

Comment: Because when I try to search a word "Disarmed" for exemple, casper don't find him :(

Comment: I'm not willing to help you anymore, because you're not following basic instructions to make your question readable (document in one line) and understandable (oppositional statements about the frame being rendered).

Comment: Sorry Artjom I'm a noob on stackoverflow ! I have update my first post with the code, is better? I want obtain information on my website (like "armed", "disarmed") but I dont know how...

Comment: Yes, that's much better. The remaining information is locked up in the images. You should post the markup around the element into the question (2 or 3 parents).

Comment: Ok, how I can paste integrality of code with frame? When I select source code on my page I have only the code starting by "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"